# How to insert data in oracle SQL developer

Tags: java, oracle, sql-insert

I would like to insert data in Oracle SQL Developer. 
On client side which I mean the web page, it displays the data has been inserted, 
but when I check it in SQL Developer, no data was inserted.

And I see this error message :

> Caused by: Error : 1400, Position : 88, Sql = INSERT INTO noticebook(NUM, NAME, EMAIL, CONTENTS)  VALUES(BOOK_NUM.NEXTVAL, :1 , :2 , :3 ) , OriginalSql = INSERT INTO noticebook(NUM, NAME, EMAIL, CONTENTS)  VALUES(BOOK_NUM.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?) , Error Msg = ORA-01400: NULL ("C##YESMONDAY"."NOTICEBOOK"."CONTENTS")

It seems like the query is incorrect, but I can not find what is wrong.

View Page (main.jsp)

```
<body>
<h1>Notice Board</h1>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="wrap_form">
        <form action="mainWritePro.jsp" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="TITLE "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea rows="15" cols="50" placeholder="INQUIRY"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="send">
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="" value="SEND" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">DELETE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">UPDATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LIST</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

noticeBoardVO.java

```
package edu.kosta.vistorsPrac;

public class noticeBoardVO { // Model
    private int num; private String name, email, contents;
    public noticeBoardVO() {} 

    public int getNum() {   return num; }
    public void setNum(int num) {   this.num = num; }
    public String getName() {   return name; }
    public void setName(String name) {  this.name = name; }
    public String getEmail() {  return email; }
    public void setEmail(String email) {    this.email = email; }
    public String getContents() {   return contents; }
    public void setContents(String contents) {  this.contents = contents; }
}
```

noticeBoardDAO.java
I assume the error occurs here..

```
public class noticeBoardDAO {// Controller

// DB Connection & Open
public static Connection loadOracleDriver() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = ConnectionHelper.getConnection("oracle");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}

// INSERT
public static void insert(Connection conn, noticeBoardVO vo) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        conn = ConnectionHelper.getConnection("oracle");
        sb.append("INSERT INTO noticebook(NUM, NAME, EMAIL, CONTENTS) ");
        sb.append(" VALUES(BOOK_NUM.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?) ");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
        pstmt.setString(1, vo.getName());
        pstmt.setString(2, vo.getEmail());
        pstmt.setString(3, vo.getContents());
        pstmt.executeUpdate(); //

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

mainWritePro.jsp (this is displayed after the user click SEND btn)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
</head>
<%
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
%>
<body>

    <jsp:useBean id="vo" class="edu.kosta.vistorsPrac.noticeBoardVO"></jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="vo" />

    <%
    Connection conn = noticeBoardDAO.loadOracleDriver();
    noticeBoardDAO.insert(conn, vo);
    %>

    <h1>Successfully Inserted !</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">DELETE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">UPDATE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LIST</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a) you should not be trying to do db inserts from your jsp, POST the data and do in a servlet.  b) As you have `e.printStackTrace();` please post your stacktrace.  Also, what is the value of `vo` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat `vo` is instance of `noticeBoardVO` class

Comment: a) for this one, this is what I was learning during the class, so first, I want to try this way :)    b)  **INSERT INTO noticebook(NUM, NAME, EMAIL, CONTENTS)  VALUES(BOOK_NUM.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?) 
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: NULL ("C##YESMONDAY"."NOTICEBOOK"."CONTENTS") can not insert.** ---> is this `e.printStackTrace();` ?  c) vo is from notiveBoardVO.

Comment: What's the output of `System.out.println(sb.toString());`?

Comment: INSERT INTO noticebook(NUM, NAME, EMAIL, CONTENTS)  VALUES(BOOK_NUM.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?)     <--- this!

Comment: To me, it is pretty much obvious: NOTICEBOOK table has column whose name is CONTENTS and it is set to be NOT NULL. However, you're trying to insert *nothing* into it, a NULL so Oracle complains about it. Are you **sure** that there is some value that is supposed to be entered into CONTENTS?

Comment: @Sam I got the reason why I couldn't insert the data thanks to @HungNguyen. I didn't put name on `textarea` in main.jsp. I did not understand what the error message meant, but now I know :)  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Littlefoot yes.. I finally gave the name to `textarea` and now I can insert data! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME"."COLUMN_NAME")

Your textarea not set name, so i think your contents value is null.

Comment: You're right! I just gave name `textarea` and now it is working. Thanks million :)